# How do I connect a USB mic to a bluetooth (also has a 3.5mm audio jack input) maybe via my laptop to have a small megaphone?

Tags: audio, speakers, mixer, amplifier

I have a [Fifine K669B](https://fifinemicrophone.com/products/usb-microphone-with-volume-control-k669-669b) USB mic, a laptop (Ubuntu as OS) and an [Anker Soundcore 2](https://www.anker.com/ca/products/variant/soundcore-2-portable-bluetooth-speaker/A3105091) Bluetooth Speaker, that also has a 3.5mm audio jack.

Is there a software or a way through an inexpensive hardware, using which I can amplify the microphone output in real time using the speaker?

The idea is to have a small scale megaphone kind of system for a small scale performance. I am a student, so I would like to spend as less as possible.

Comment: You could probably do it with [Jack](https://jackaudio.org) but the latency will drive you nuts.

Comment: I think you'd be better served by asking this question on either the software or hardware recommendations stack exchange sites. It's not a sound design question as per our scope.

Answer (score -1):

I can't specify the exact details, but you can probably set up 2 devices (or 2 browser tabs), each logged in to a different Discord account and then connect the microphone to one, and the speaker to the other. Have one account call the other, and set the input for one account to the microphone, and the output of the other account to the speaker.

Haven't actually tried this, but I imagine it would work.